# Could not cast value of type '__NSCFDictionary' to 'NSArray

Tags: json, swift

I make a GET request to the Blockchain API and here is what I get:

```
{
    "USD": {
        "15m": 1973.51,
        "last": 1973.51,
        "buy": 1973.51,
        "sell": 1970.5,
        "symbol": "$"
    },
    "ISK": {
        "15m": 204455.64,
        "last": 204455.64,
        "buy": 204455.64,
        "sell": 204143.8,
        "symbol": "kr"
    },
    "HKD": {
        "15m": 15400.36,
        "last": 15400.36,
        "buy": 15400.36,
        "sell": 15376.88,
        "symbol": "$"
    },
    "TWD": {
        "15m": 59959.18,
        "last": 59959.18,
        "buy": 59959.18,
        "sell": 59867.73,
        "symbol": "NT$"
    }
}
```

I try to parse the USD sub-object, and this is my code:

```
let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                print(error);

            } else {

                let responseData = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8);
                print(responseData);
                var USD = [String]()
                do{
                    if let ipString = NSString(data:data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) {
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [NSDictionary];
                        USD = json.map { ($0 as! [String: AnyObject])["USD"] as! String }


                    }
                }
                catch{
                    print("Parse JSON failed")
                }
            }
        })
```

But when I run it, there is an error:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM'  to 'NSArray'

I know `USD` is more like a `[String:AnyObject]`, but it did not work either. Any solutions?

Comment: Why are you using `NSString` and `NSDictionary`?

Answer (score 0):

Here none of your json response is array type, all are dictionary type. Do like this, hope it will solve your problem:

```
var USD = [String: AnyObject]()
    do{
        if let ipString = NSString(data:data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: AnyObject];
            if let usd = json.["USD"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
                USD = usd
            }


        }
    }
    catch{
        print("Parse JSON failed")
    }
```